# How to host dynamic website which uses MongoDB, Node, Stripe (since Github Pages won't work?)

Tags: mongodb, server, hosting, shopping-cart, github-pages

Thus far I have enjoyed Github Pages for putting up my webpages and projects online where others can view and interact with them. This is also handy for displaying and linking to things I've worked on in my portfolio.

My newest project, a tutorial on building shopping cart with thorough functionality, involves Node.js, Express.js, MongoDB, Passport.js, Stripe.js.

[Link to Shopping Cart Repository](https://github.com/PolarisTLX/Shopping-Cart-MongoDB-and-Node)

The gh-pages version of the site: [Github Pages version of the repository](https://polaristlx.github.io/Shopping-Cart-MongoDB-and-Node/)  gives a 404 Error. As I understand, because this involves interacting with a server (MongoDB and Node), this is a "dynamic page", whereas Github Pages can only host "static pages".

Is there a way that I can have this up and running online so that others can see and interact with it?

If not, is another solution to simply record and post a video of the website in action?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm interested too, did you find where to host your site?

Comment: @rraalivv, I have since learned GitHub pages does not support anything beyond static pages. If your website uses a back-end / server, then you need something like Heroku to host it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying heroku. Also back4app seems to work for node-js apps too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Node you can use [Heroku.com](https://www.heroku.com)

And for MongoDB I think you can find a free hosted on internet, either you can maybe create a local MongoBD server as local with Node